# jQuery on click returns wrong element when using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements with the same class. I want to get the exact element when I click on it. When I click on the `first element`, I get the correct answer while when I click on the nested element (e.g. `first sub element`), I get two results: `first sub element` as well as `first element`. What I don't understand is that when I click on an element, shouldn't I get only that element that this event was triggered for? I want to get only `first sub element` when I click on that li. How can I get this result?

```js
$(document).on('click', "li.category", function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="category">first element
      <ul>
        <li class="category">first sub element</li>
        <li class="category">second sub element</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">second element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using event delegation and the way event delegation works is that jQuery events (say click event here) walks up the DOM tree from the innermost target to the element that the delegation was bound to

In other words when you click on `first sub element` actually you also click on parent of the element (I mean `first element`) too, because your target is `li.category` and both of them are your target.

Fast fixed is using `event.stopPropagation()` to stop propagating click event from innermost to parent, like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', "li.category", function(e){
  alert($(this).text());
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="category">first element
      <ul>
        <li class="category">first sub element</li>
        <li class="category">second sub element</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">second element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```js
$('.category').on('click', function(){  
  let text = $(this)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()
  alert(text);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="category">first element
      <ul>
        <li class="category">first sub element</li>
        <li class="category">second sub element</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">second element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text()` in a parent element results in returning the text of all its children.
So clicking on `first element` would have the output

```
First element
First Sub element
Second sub element
```

since you've mentioned you are getting correct output, I am assuming this is what you want.

Otherwise, refer [here](https://www.viralpatel.net/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/) to get text for only *that* li

Coming to the problem, you want to get the exact element which was clicked on. When you click on any sub `.category`, it fires click for the parent `.category` as well and the function runs twice. To avoid this, use `target`

```
$(document).on('click', "li.category", function(e){
  var el = e.target
  if( this == el)
     alert($(el).text())
})
```

Answer (score -2):

There's an easiest way to do it, You can simply improve your code structure like changing `<li class="category">first element` to `<li class="category"><span class="label">first element</span>` and now in javascript you change the query to:

1. `alert($(this).find('.label').text());`
2. Or `$(document).on('click', "li.category .label", function(){`

Let me know if you have any other thoughts.